# Terminal 3 Heathrow - Bad facilities can I go into Terminal 2 first?

Tags: food-and-drink, lhr, security

We are flying to America with Virgin (LHR T3) and wanted to have a big breakfast but the options are not great in Terminal 3. Is there any way we can check the bags in at T3, walk over to T2, go through security grab some scran, then go back over the T3 for the flight?

Comment: Can't you get decent food land-side at T2? The terminals are quite close to each other, you can walk between Terminals 2 and 3 via the pedestrian underpass.

Comment: In many airports trying to enter the departures area of the wrong terminal will at least trigger an alert when they scan your boarding pass (mostly to prevent people from getting lost). In LHR you have the added issue that the airside shuttles leave from the arrivals area, not departures, so I’m not sure it would even be possible (and if it were you would have to budget quite a bit of additional time, and go through security twice).

Comment: Also what exactly is it you are missing in T3? Many of the airside restaurants are exactly the same in both…

Comment: @WeatherVane Looks like it, T2 and T3

Comment: Thanks everyone. Ended up at T3's Wagamamas. Had a full English but with a twist. It was OK, but I'm sure they have a market for a decent greasy spoon ;o).

Answer (score 6):

T3 landside has a pub that does a Full English - The Oceanic.  You won't beat that sort of thing for a big breakfast at the airport.

T2 has an equivalent, the Queens Arms, also landside.

So your best bet could be to eat before security.  But T3 also has Spuntino in departures "For breakfast, tuck in to ... classic proper English breakfast."

If none of those will do, you'll need to get something before heading to the airport, as the options are pretty similar between the 2 terminals

Comment: Or maybe wait until arrival in the US, where ‘big breakfast’ is likely to be (much) bigger than in a UK airport :-)

Comment: @Traveller The solution must be 2 breakfasts, roughly matching time zones.  Just get them the right way round: a fry-up in the UK, and pancakes in the US is better than the reverse (especially for me as vegetarian versions seem harder to find in the US, or did when I was there some years ago)